# How do I determine the side effects of a Java function?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on an object, specifically its one function, which looks like this:

```
public class Dog {
    private ArrayList<Paw> paws;
    private double age;
    private Tongue tongue;

    public Dog(ArrayList<Paw> paws, double age, Tongue tongue) {
        this.paws = paws;
        this.age = age;
        this.tongue = tongue;
    }

    public void bark() {
        // ... about 100 lines of side effects operating
        // on the object's global members ...
    }
}
```

I really want to fix these side effects and refactor the object into functions that do only one thing.

Is there an automated process in Eclipse to mark possible side effects?

If not, is there a manual algorithm I can follow so I don't get lost down the rabbit hole?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would create a unit test which tests your old `Dog` class including all "side effects" (not quite sure what you mean here).

Assuming your unit test passes, you can then start the refactoring (using Eclipse, selecting appropriate lines and using right-click, Refactor, Extract Method could be your friend here) and keep using your unit test to check whether the refactoring has broken anything.

EDIT:

To find out what else is changing the attributes of your `Paw` and `Tongue` classes, you could set modification watchpoints (i.e. set a breakpoint on the attributes, right click on the breakpoint, Breakpoint properties, untick "access") on any attributes used by `bark()`, then when you are running your app in the debugger, every time anything changes a property, the debugger will stop.

Comment: By side effect I meant anything which changes the data of the objects passed into the method. This answer doesn't really work because it begs the question. If my question is, "How do I refactor this method?" then a circular answer would be to say, "Unit test the method and then refactor it." I appreciate the extract method and the unit test suggestion - but I believe you're one step ahead of where I am.

Comment: That's very useful - I'm going to go try it (and the other methods). If there aren't any better answers in a little bit I'll accept this one for the access suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Unit tests and refactoring should often (if not always) walk together.

Comment: I almost downvoted this.  If a method is 100 lines of code generating a lot of side effects, creating the unit tests is pretty much impossible.  It sounds like OP has no idea what the code is supposed to do, and that is why he is refactoring to understand it.  _After_ OP has refactored into "functions that do only one thing" then he/she can write unit tests.

Comment: @user949300 You are correct in critiquing the first part of their beny23's answer in that way. However, the second (edited) portion is useful advice.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an automated process.

As for a manual algorithm, if you make all the class fields `final`, you will get an error *most* places they are modified as a side effect of `bark()`.  (An alternative is to rename them but that also flags reads from them)   So you can find the side effects very easily.  Slowly refactor into smaller functions until `bark()` has no errors.

The ArrayList paws will *not* be covered by the `final` trick, cause you can still `add(), remove()` etc. from it.  So that is probably one to rename.

Comment: The final trick is useful, thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in some cases in the method because the method copies the data from the global into a local variable (or the method calls another method on the global variable).

Comment: It it copies *all* of the data and no references are kept, then it doesn't count as a *side effect*. A side effect is only when the fields are changed, not when read. But OK, if it copies a reference from a list and then changes that element: there's your "hidden" side effect...

Comment: I've added a comment below the question about other tricks to minimize state changes (`unmodifiableList` and using `birthday` instead of `age`).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an automated process in Eclipse to mark possible side
>   effects?

No, there isn't.

> If not, is there a manual algorithm I can follow so I don't get lost
>   down the rabbit hole?

You can start by commenting (`ctrl + /`) all the object's global members. So in your function you will have words underlined on red, which you have to repair with argument passing or local variables. Later uncomment members. In Eclipse you can also use a shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + M` for method extracting. For refectoring there is also a very useful shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + R` for changing variable names.

Comment: The commenting is useful, thank you. I will start by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can check any direct referencing when you use **mark occurrences**, and then point at any field. You can also **Search** for **Write access** for each field in the search menu, *but beware that this doesn't show indirect changes*. To find indirect changes you also need to also search for **Read Access** and then find out how all the (mutable) references are used. You should do this for parameters as well, to avoid side effects **external** to your class. Finally, any calls to static methods and fields should be reviewed.

Otherwise I unfortunately don't know any way of listing (possible) side effects in any IDE. Note that any function call on any object such as a "paw" in the list of `Paw`s may also create a side effect. That makes it near impossible to check against *every* side effect. Still, it would be nice to have more insight.

---

Manually you can do the following (get ready!):

The first thing to do is to minimize state changes. If you minimize state then you'll automatically also minimize possible changes to the state, i.e. side effects. In this case the field `age` is a well known pitfall as `age` changes with time: you should document the birthday instead and calculate the age either outside of the class, or using a function that accepts a (current) date. *If you remove all possible state changes then your class instances are immutable and you don't need to worry about side effects anymore.*

The methods of making basic values (integers, characters and the like) and references immutable has already been mentioned: make them final fields. There are other things though: you should also mark your class `final` if you haven't designed it to be extended using child classes. If the class itself is not final then you can make specific functions final. Always expose a minimal set of methods using the right access modifiers.

Another trick is to use [`List.copyOf(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) on the given set of paws when assigning it to the field (presuming you don't have a `removePaw`method of course). This creates a defensive copy, but only if deemed necessary. However, to avoid side effects in other parts of the application you should make sure that `Paw` is immutable as well. Guava and other libraries also have immutable lists that cannot be changed by neither the class or the user that constructed the class.

Note that creating immutable classes is directly related to class design. If you have a dog that has side effects because it barks then you are doing something wrong. If anything, the dog itself doesn't change significantly because it barks. If you e.g. want to count the number or loudness of a bark, **you should register it outside of the class instance, not within**. Always try and minimize functionality of a class; it inherently allows you to minimize state change.

In newer Java versions you could use records instead. These are data classes that are immutable by default. Closely related ideas are Java enums, factories & factory methods. Please read the latest version of "Effective Java" if you want to know more about those.

---

If you don't have any state changes left over then your object is immutable and you don't have to worry about side effects anymore. Note that internally created instances don't need to be immutable, as long as you don't share their reference outside of your class. The `Dog` class as it is shown in the question would be perfectly suitable for creating an immutable data class (which generally also has `hashCode` and `equals` methods and is marked `Serializable`).

If you still have methods that create side effects then you should test them using Unit tests. Of course, at this stage it would be nice if the number of ways that callers can perform state changes is minimized, and that the changes they can make are clearly bounded.